# How do I make it so that it only displays the Game Over panel after all buttons are disabled?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, multidimensional-array

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    boolean hasProblemsleft = true;
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if(source == quit)
    {
    cards.show(c, "Introduction");
    for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            buttons[row][col].setEnabled(true);
    }
    for(int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    for(int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
        {
        if(source == buttons[row][col])
        {
            questions.showTimer(row, col);
            buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false); // disables button after user                                                                                               /                                                              //clicks on it
        }
        else if(buttons[row][col].isEnabled())
        {
            hasProblemsleft = false;
            }
        }
        if(hasProblemsleft)
        {
        cards.show(c, "Game Over!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could someone please help me fix the spacing? I'm not so sure how to do it... sorry. Thank you very much for any help in advance.

Comment: 1) To use code formatting, select the code sample and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting form.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html). 3) For greater clarity in communication, repeat the question in the body of the message.

Comment: As an aside, though I don't understand the code snippet very well, it seems that *either* the `quit` button should have a separate `ActionListener`, *or* that the entire looping structures for the other buttons should be put in an `else` condition.  The illogical/inconsistent indentation of the code snippet does not help in understanding it.  ..And line 18 is **very** long.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson got you off to a good start, but you need to carry on. Fixing the comments and indentation will help _you_, as well as the reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a separate set of nested for loops (after the nested loops above) to check if every button is disabled, and if so, display your game over panel.

**edit 1:**
You use one set of nested loops to disable the button after pressing it, and the second set to check of all the buttons are disabled. e.g.,

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object source = e.getSource();
      if (source == quit) {
         cards.show(c, "Introduction");
         for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
               buttons[row][col].setEnabled(true);
      } else { // don't forget this important else!
         for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) { // use curly braces for *ALL*
                                             // loops/blocks
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
               if (source == buttons[row][col]) {
                  questions.showTimer(row, col);
                  buttons[row][col].setEnabled(false);
               }
            }
         }

         boolean done = true;
         for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
               if (buttons[row][col].isEnabled()) {
                  done = false;
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
         if (done) {
            cards.show(c, "Game Over!");
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Ok. May I have an example? If not, could you explain more what you mean? I really don't understand...sorry... :(

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: ok after using your code...the only problem is that when i click on the last button, it shows the gameover panel :(

Comment: @thynoob, then fix the logic to do what you want.

Comment: @HFOE: `// use curly braces for *ALL* loops/blocks`  +1  Agreed.  I'm guessing that lines 5 & 6 are left as an exercise for the OP? ;)  Nicely formatted, BTW.  :-)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: What is OP?

Comment: @thynoob:  OP is short for 'original poster'.  In this thread it is you.  ;)